# Correct regular expression to match the begin of XSS vector

Tags: c#, regex, string, xss

I need to specify the correct regular expression to get the first symbols of the XSS vector. On C#. For example, I have a vector:

```
});alert('XSS');</script>
"); alert('XSS');
```

And my regular expression:

```
 Regex firstPart = new Regex(@"""|\*/|\""|\}|\)|\)\}|\}\)|'|</script><script>|'>|"">|""\)|\]|'\]|'\)|'\}");
```

Defines characters } and ) and \" etc
But it does not define for example the characters )} or }) or ""(double quotes) or '> or '].
How do I change the expression to make everything work completely?

Comment: I don't understand XSS and C#, but did you ever try this https://regex101.com/?

Comment: No, i didn't.
Thanks, I'll try